# python string variable changes '\b' into '\x08' and '\a' into '\x07' and similarly for some number and characters too? why?

Tags: python, string, escaping, filepath

When I am using `filename="media\documents\dog_bark.wav"`
Python works fine and my intended functionality works.

But with `filename="media\documents\afile1.wav"`,  `filename="media\documents\732-20.wav"` and similar other selected filepaths it's changing the first character of the filename to `\x07`, I have also seen `\x08` and so on

Why does this happen and is there any solution for this?

Comment: Always use raw strings (`r'...'`) when dealing with backsplashes in strings.

Comment: It is better to use forward slashes for a [Windows path in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953834/windows-path-in-python) anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using like that `"media\\documents\\afile1.wav"` , right?
with double **\**

"media\documents **\a**file1.wav" **\a** is a char

"media\documents **\7**32-20.wav" **\7** is a char also

when you use **\d** it is not a char so it changing to **\\d** in a string

you can use `r" RAW STRING "` if you do not want to care about it.